# How do I /tp an Armor Stand to me but half a block away or something?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-commands

So I've been trying to /tp a "pet" which is an armor stand with a player head on it but when I try making it follow me it just teleports into me instead of next to me.
Any tips?
Thanks.

Comment: Welcome to Arqade! What have you tried?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Differing from the other answers, this should give you a more natural behaviour:

`execute as @e[type=armor_stand,tag=pet] at @s unless entity @p[distance=..0.5] facing entity @p feet positioned ^ ^ ^0.3 run tp @s ~ ~ ~`

The armorstand will follow the closest player, but it isn't locked to be always exactly left or right to the player. Instead it will follow in the direction the player runs.

Let me split the command:

`execute as @e[type=armor_stand,tag=pet] at @s`

Find all armorstands and execute everything that follows relative to their position.

`unless entity @p[distance=..0.5]`

If the nearest player is already less than 0.5 blocks away, don't do anything. If you find, that 0.5 blocks distance is too less, change it here.

`facing entity @p feet`

Face the feet of the closest player.

`positioned ^ ^ ^0.3`

Move the position 0.3 blocks to the front. Because we are facing the nearest player, this is 0.3 blocks closer to the nearest player. Values smaller than 0.3 will mean, that the pet follows you slower. Higher values will result in it sticking to you.

`run tp @s ~ ~0.1 ~`

Teleport the pet to the position determined by the flags before, but 0.1 blocks above this. The 0.1 will make it less likely to sink into the ground, when the player jumps up blocks.

Comment: Thank you so much! It worked.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a few commands that should help.

Selector means the selector that selects the armor stand; for example, [name="pet"] or [tag="pet"].

`/execute at player run tp @e[selector] ^-0.5 ^ ^`

I'll break this command down.

**/execute at player**

This means "run everything after this at the location of player".

**run tp @e[selector]**

This means teleport the entities matched by @e[selector].

**^0.5 ^ ^**

This is using Caret Positioning, meaning relative to the head of the target entity. However, remember that we are running the command at the location of the player, so it's relative to the *player's* head.

The first caret (^0.5) means position 0.5 blocks left to the player's head.

Every other value stays the same, becuase their is nothing after the caret.

Answer (score 0):

Its pretty simple.

if you want it to the side of you you might do

```
/execute at player run tp @e[type=armor_stand,<put if you have more specific tags>] ^-0.5 ^ ^
```

and simply if you want it in the other side remove the "-" or to make it further increase the number.

if you want it in front of you it would be a little harder where you would need to make an armor stand in your position that is always pointing to the front but not up or down.

Comment: Thank you, it didn't work but I still appreciate it!